# WebMatrix social authentication MVC integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth, integration, webmatrix

Is there any article or ideas how to use/move/intergrate social authentication from WebMatrix 2 to MVC 4. I've googled internet but didn't found any info about possibility to add references to WebMatrix namespaces/libraries to MVC project. I've read following article http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/the-top-features-in-web-pages-2-developer-preview#oauthsetup and want to use WebMatrix.Security in MVC project

Comment: Have you found any articles/ideas since you asked this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth authentication on website now built-in, question closed

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to upgrade your project from simple ASP.NET Razor pages to a full MVC 4 project, I recommend moving from WebMatrix to Visual Web Developer:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express

Everything you're trying to do here with the social auth libraries should work perfectly well in VS, and there are even a few NuGet packages that can make it easy.  WebMatrix is meant to get you running with ASP.NET and Razor, but VS is going to give you a fuller experience.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Project already written on ASP.NET MVC, but i found that implementation of authentication in social networks looks better in WebMatrix, so that what i'm asking for. Question is how to use classes from WebMatrix in MVC but not about what is WebMatrix/Visual Studio/Razor... etc

Comment: To use the classes for social auth you should only really need to add a reference to WebMatrix.WebData to your MVC project.  Just right click on references,  add reference, choose 'WebMatrix.WebData', and ensure that copy local is set to true.

Comment: @JustinBeckwith hi, and what about database tables?. webmatrix installation of social auth includes OAuthMembership table in the database. do you believe that using standard auth from mvc plus oauthmembership and webmatrix.webdata will work directly?

Answer (score 0):

here you will find a step by step solution to migrate webmatrix-webpages apps into asp.net mvc. check that you can find the login area - were you will figure out the social auth login too -  in order to migrate it to mvc too.

information:

The Web Pages page-centric programming model supported by WebMatrix is a great way to get Web apps up and running. If you later decide that embracing ASP.NET MVC would give you more flexibility, you're covered. We’ll explain why you might choose to migrate and show you how to do it.

read the article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148144.aspx

download code: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201105ASPNET/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5601